# Why I cant link gRPC into my static library?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have compiled gRPC 1.23.0 with all dependencies(Protobuf, a-arec, etc).

After translating my `.proto` file into `*.grpc.pb.*` and `*.pb.*` files, I added it to VS project and successfully compiled it to `.exe` file.

But after I switched `Configuration type` property into `Dynamic library` or `Static library`(I really need exactly `Static library`), it compiled without errors, but on linking step in `Build output` I see >2000 link warnings like this:

```
1>grpc++_unsecure.lib(pb_encode.obj) : warning LNK4006: _pb_encode_submessage already defined in grpc++.lib(pb_encode.obj); second definition ignored
1>grpc++_unsecure.lib(pb_encode.obj) : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
1>grpc++_unsecure.lib(codegen_init.obj) : warning LNK4006: "class grpc::CoreCodegenInterface * grpc::g_core_codegen_interface" (?g_core_codegen_interface@grpc@@3PAVCoreCodegenInterface@1@A) already defined in grpc++.lib(codegen_init.obj); second definition ignored
1>grpc++_unsecure.lib(codegen_init.obj) : warning LNK4006: "class grpc::GrpcLibraryInterface * grpc::g_glip" (?g_glip@grpc@@3PAVGrpcLibraryInterface@1@A) already defined in grpc++.lib(codegen_init.obj); second definition ignored
1>grpc++_unsecure.lib(codegen_init.obj) : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
1>grpc_unsecure.lib(init.obj) : warning LNK4006: _grpc_register_plugin already defined in grpc.lib(init.obj); second definition ignored
1>grpc_unsecure.lib(init.obj) : warning LNK4006: _grpc_init already defined in grpc.lib(init.obj); second definition ignored
1>grpc_unsecure.lib(init.obj) : warning LNK4006: _grpc_shutdown already defined in grpc.lib(init.obj); second definition ignored
1>grpc_unsecure.lib(init.obj) : warning LNK4006: _grpc_is_initialized already defined in grpc.lib(init.obj); second definition ignored
```

And finally linking ends with error:

```
1>libprotobufd.lib(version.res) : fatal error LNK1241: resource file libprotocd.lib(version.res) already specified
```

This error appears only for `Debug` configuration. On `Release` it links successful, but also with link warnings.

What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: Looks like you're linking to two different copies of the grpc static library, remove one of them

Comment: Yeh, it's true. I use conan, which generate `.props` file for me and there is `<Link>` and `<Lib>` sections and, as I understand, VS use both sections in `Static Library` configuration. After I have redefined `<Lib>` section, my project compiled without warnings and errors. Thanks!

Comment: After addition investigation, I found that this problem affected only with `conan` version = 1.19.0 and fixed in 1.19.1. https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/5844